# How to test cookie which created by service in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

#### route

```php
Route::get('/token', [\App\Http\Controllers\TokenController::class, 'index']);
```

#### TokenController.php

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\Token;

class TokenController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $tokenService = app(Token::class);

        return $tokenService->handle('https://www.nba.com');
    }
}
```

#### Token Service

```php
namespace App\Services;

class Token
{
    public function handle(string $redirect)
    {
        return redirect($redirect)->withCookie(cookie('token', 'abcd'));
    }
}
```

I want to leave a token in cookies when the user enters the page and redirect to another URL, I am sure the cookie was saved when I check on the browser, but I don't know to do the test that **token service did save the cookie** in the unit test.

first try

```php
namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Services\Token;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
use Tests\TestCase;

class TokenTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testToken()
    {
        app(Token::class)->handle('https://www.nba.com');

        dd(Cookie::get('token')); // null
    }
}
```

second try

```php
namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Services\Token;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Tests\TestCase;

class TokenTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testToken()
    {
        app(Token::class)->handle('https://www.nba.com');

        Route::get('view-cookie', function (Request $request) {
            return $request->cookie('token');
        });

        $response = $this->get('/view-cookie');

        dd($response->getContent()); // ""
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you check the response returned from `handle` to see if the cookie is there

Comment: if I get cookies from handle, it's on headers, can I take it as a successful result?

Comment: and what would that mean if the response has the cookie in the headers?